# Linking Fullcalendar items to data in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I'm currently using the fullcalendar.io in my application and I'm in the process of trying to add the ability to click on an existing event to open the details in a separate page. The entries on the calendar are generated through props and mapped to place them on the correct date. I'm using the navigate function to pull the request by id, but I am not having any luck carrying over the id from the mapped request. Anyone have any experience working with the fullcalendar.io?

Please see my code below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

//Component Imports
// import { formatDate } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'

//Utility Imports
import { createEventId } from './event-utils'

const FullCal = (props)=> {

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [weekendsVisible, setWeekendsVisible] = useState(true)
  const [currentEvents, setCurrentEvents] = useState([])
  const [elId, setElId] = useState('')
  // const [numberEvents, setNumberEvents] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I Only run once (When the component gets mounted)") 
    handleEvents()
  },[props.ptoRequests]);

  const handleWeekendsToggle = () => {
    setWeekendsVisible(!weekendsVisible)
    console.log(weekendsVisible)
  }
    
  // const handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
  //   let title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event')
  //   let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar

  //   calendarApi.unselect() // clear date selection

  //   if (title) {
  //     calendarApi.addEvent({
  //       id: createEventId(),
  //       title,
  //       start: selectInfo.startStr,
  //       end: selectInfo.endStr,
  //       allDay: selectInfo.allDay
  //     })
  //   }
  // }


  function handleEvents(){
    let events = props.ptoRequests.map(function (event){
      console.log(event.id)
      return {
        title: event.employee.employee_first_name,
        department: event.employee.department,
        start: event.date_requested,
        end: event.date_requested,
        requestid: event.id,
        }
      }
    )
    setCurrentEvents(events)
  }console.log(currentEvents)

  const handleEventClick = (selectInfo) => {
    navigate(`/timeoffrequest/${selectInfo.id}`);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className='demo-app'>
      <div className='demo-app-sidebar-section'>
        <label>
          <input
            type='checkbox'
            checked={weekendsVisible}
            onChange={handleWeekendsToggle}
          >
          </input>
          Show Weekends
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className='demo-app-main'>
        <FullCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          headerToolbar={{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
          }}
          initialView='dayGridMonth'
          editable={true}
          selectable={true}
          selectMirror={true}
          dayMaxEvents={true}
          weekends={weekendsVisible}
          events={currentEvents}
          // initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS} // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
          // select={handleDateSelect}
          // eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
          eventClick={handleEventClick}
          // eventsSet={handleEvents} // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
          /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
          eventAdd={function(){}}
          eventChange={function(){}}
          eventRemove={function(){}}
          */
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}
export default FullCal
```

I tried to use a click handler to pull the event by id, but the events are mapped in the calendar and I can't seem to pull the id of each event back.

```
  const handleEventClick = (selectInfo) => {
    navigate(`/timeoffrequest/${selectInfo.id}`);
  }
```